# Stata - Count observations within window

Tags: stata

I am looking to create a variable (`COUNT_WITHIN_2_DAYS`) that is the count of observations in a date range. The range would be the stated date +/- 2 days.

```
 ID#          DATE          COUNT_WITHIN_2_DAYS
  1         1/1/2000                3
  2         1/2/2000                4
  5         1/2/2000                4
  6         1/4/2000                3
  9        1/12/2000                1
 11         3/1/2001                2
 12         3/3/2000                4
 16         3/4/2000                3
 18         3/5/2000                3
 21         3/8/2000                1
```

I tried an `egen` with an `if` command but that did not work

Comment: Don't confuse or conflate the `if` command and the `if` qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution involves looping over all observations and uses the fact that you can compute with dates as you would with integers, after giving the date variable a *date format*. (These dates are just integers. See e.g. `help datetime` for details).

Every observation is compared with the one observation that is fixed by the loop. `ind == 1` for those observations in which the absolute difference is `<= 2`. Afterwards, I use `summarize` to add-up
the number of such observations. Finally, the result of the sum is assigned to the fixed observation using the variable `counter`. The procedure is repeated until each observation has been fixed.

```
clear all
set more off

*-------------- example data ----------------
input ///
id str15 date 
  1         "1/1/2000"                
  2         "1/2/2000"                
  5         "1/2/2000"                
  6         "1/4/2000"                
  9        "1/12/2000"                
 11         "3/1/2001"                
 12         "3/3/2000"                
 16         "3/4/2000"                
 18         "3/5/2000"                
 21         "3/8/2000"               
 end

gen date2 = date(date, "MDY")
format date2 %td

drop date
rename date2 date

sort date
list

*------------ what you want ------------------

gen counter = .
gen ind = .
forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    replace ind = abs(date - date[`i']) <= 2

    summarize ind, meanonly
    replace counter = r(sum) in `i'
}

drop ind
list
```

Comment: See SJ Tip on "Events in intervals" at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0033

Comment: Just to add that if data were regularly spaced in time, this would be a trivial addition of values in previous, present, and following observations. It's the irregular spacing of times that gives the problem its bite.